# Create loop which redirects to another page after condition is met

Tags: php, redirect, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a loop, which redirects to another script when the condition is met. But at the moment, it meets the condition, ends the loop, but doesn't redirect to the script. Nothing I have done works...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require '../config/connection.php';
session_name('ppRemember');
session_set_cookie_params(86400);
session_start();
//get value from database. if is pending then display loading else display summary. if is complete but no session set say session has expired
if (isset($_SESSION['txnId'])) {
if ($_SESSION['txnId']==true) {
    header('Location: ../confirmation');
    die();
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body> 
<div id="basket-empty" title="Success" style="display:none;">
<p>Basket emptied</p>
</div>
<div id="confirm-empty" title="Confirm" style="display:none;">
<p>Are you sure you want to empty your basket?</p>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header" class="without-secondary-menu">
                <div class="section clearfix">
                    <div id="logo-caption">
                        <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home" id="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="caption">
                    </div>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <ul id="main-menu-links" class="links clearfix">
                            <li class="menu-2 active-trail active"><a href="../index"> Order Online </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-9"><a href="../my-account"> My Account </a></li>
                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['id']) {?>
                            <li class="menu-10"><a href="../login"> Sign In </a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <li class="menu-5"><a href="../getaquote"> Get a Quote </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-6"><a href="../contactus"> Contact Us </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-11"><a href="../news"> News </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-8"><a href="../uploads"> Uploads </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-7"><a href="../downloads"> Downloads </a></li>
                        </ul>           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>
                <div id="panel" class="clearfix">
                    <div id="account-links">
                        <ul class="username">
                            <li><span class="account-links"><a href="../my-account">You are logged in as <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b></a></span>
                            <span class="logout"><a href="../destroy">Logout</a></span></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>  
        <div id="main-wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <div id="main" class="clearfix">
                <div class="content">
                    <a id="main-content"></a>
                    <div class="tabs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="region region-content">
                        <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div id="node-1" class="clearfix">
                                    <div class="content clearfix">
                                        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['txnId'])) {
                                        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { ?>
                                        <div class="loading2" style="height:300px;">
                                            <span class="text2"><font size="6pt"><b>Loading....</b></font></span>
                                            <img src="../images/ajax-loader2.gif"/><br />
                                            <font size="3pt"><b>Please wait a moment whilst we process your payment</b></font><br />
                                            <font size="1pt"><b>Click <a href="/order/complete">here</a> to reload after 10 seconds</b></font>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php }
                                        } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer-wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
                        <div class="region region-footer">
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="column1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column2">
                                                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html> 
<?php
$trans = $_SESSION['transaction_id'];
$clientId = $_SESSION['id'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['txnId'])){
    while ($_SESSION['txnId']!=true) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "#####", "#####", "######");
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `txn_id` FROM `trans` AS t, `order_table` AS ot, `customer_order_details` AS cod WHERE t.transaction_id=?
         && t.transaction_id = ot.transaction_id && ot.customer_order_details_id = cod.customer_order_details_id && cod.client_id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ii',$trans,$clientId);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->store_result(); 
            $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
            if ($num_rows>=1) {
                $stmt->bind_result($txnidrow);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
                $_SESSION['CARRYTXNID'] = $txnidrow;    
                $_SESSION['txnId'] = true;
            }
        }
    } 
}
header('Location: ../confirmation');
die();
}
```

?>

Any headway is greatly appreciated. I've tried a do while loop, header without die/exit. I've removed all code and redirected the page on it's own, ran the script and all is fine. Etc, etc. I echo'd something to make sure that the condition is finally met, as well.

Comment: You might have some headers set already before redirect. Do you get any php errors?

Comment: Does the do while loop ends always? May it is goes to infinite loop.

Comment: Relative paths for `Location:` headers are a violation of the HTTP standard. You should always use absolute URLs for redirects as anything else cannot be assumed to work everywhere (or anywhere). [Ref](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

Comment: I assume so, because if go directly to confirmation script, which only loads if $_SESSION['txnId'] = true;, it loads  @Nish

Comment: @Pam My money here is on Dainis Abols being correct. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script, and I suspect you will see some errors. His code in his answer below also looks more like what you want to be doing.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ######/order/complete.php:134) in ########/order/complete.php on line 197 @DaveRandom

Comment: @Dainis Abols 
I have added the code. The header error seems to be caused by the loading div? I don't see why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your edit, the solution here is actually quite simple - all you need to do is move the redirect code to the top of the page:

```
<?php

  define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
  require '../config/connection.php';

  session_name('ppRemember');
  session_set_cookie_params(86400);
  session_start();

  $trans = $_SESSION['transaction_id'];
  $clientId = $_SESSION['id'];

  //get value from database. if is pending then display loading else display summary. if is complete but no session set say session has expired
  if (isset($_SESSION['txnId'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['txnId']==true) {
      header('Location: ../confirmation');
      die();
    }
  } else {
    while (!$_SESSION['txnId']) {
      $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "#####", "#####", "######");
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT `txn_id`
        FROM `trans` AS t, `order_table` AS ot, `customer_order_details` AS cod
        WHERE t.transaction_id = ?
           && t.transaction_id = ot.transaction_id
           && ot.customer_order_details_id = cod.customer_order_details_id
           && cod.client_id = ?
      ");
      $stmt->bind_param('ii', $trans, $clientId);
      if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($num_rows>=1) {
          $stmt->bind_result($txnidrow);
          $stmt->fetch();
          $stmt->free_result();
          $stmt->close();
          $_SESSION['CARRYTXNID'] = $txnidrow;    
          $_SESSION['txnId'] = true;
        }
      }
    } 
  }
  header('Location: ../confirmation');
  die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body> 
<div id="basket-empty" title="Success" style="display:none;">
<p>Basket emptied</p>
</div>
<div id="confirm-empty" title="Confirm" style="display:none;">
<p>Are you sure you want to empty your basket?</p>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header" class="without-secondary-menu">
                <div class="section clearfix">
                    <div id="logo-caption">
                        <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home" id="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="caption">
                    </div>
                    <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
                        <ul id="main-menu-links" class="links clearfix">
                            <li class="menu-2 active-trail active"><a href="../index"> Order Online </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-9"><a href="../my-account"> My Account </a></li>
                            <?php if (!$_SESSION['id']) {?>
                            <li class="menu-10"><a href="../login"> Sign In </a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <li class="menu-5"><a href="../getaquote"> Get a Quote </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-6"><a href="../contactus"> Contact Us </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-11"><a href="../news"> News </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-8"><a href="../uploads"> Uploads </a></li>
                            <li class="menu-7"><a href="../downloads"> Downloads </a></li>
                        </ul>           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>
                <div id="panel" class="clearfix">
                    <div id="account-links">
                        <ul class="username">
                            <li><span class="account-links"><a href="../my-account">You are logged in as <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b></a></span>
                            <span class="logout"><a href="../destroy">Logout</a></span></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>  
        <div id="main-wrapper" class="clearfix">
            <div id="main" class="clearfix">
                <div class="content">
                    <a id="main-content"></a>
                    <div class="tabs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="region region-content">
                        <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div id="node-1" class="clearfix">
                                    <div class="content clearfix">
                                        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['txnId'])) {
                                        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { ?>
                                        <div class="loading2" style="height:300px;">
                                            <span class="text2"><font size="6pt"><b>Loading....</b></font></span>
                                            <img src="../images/ajax-loader2.gif"/><br />
                                            <font size="3pt"><b>Please wait a moment whilst we process your payment</b></font><br />
                                            <font size="1pt"><b>Click <a href="/order/complete">here</a> to reload after 10 seconds</b></font>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php }
                                        } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer-wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
                        <div class="region region-footer">
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="column1">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column2">
                                                                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$bool = false;
while (!$bool) {
   //do you stuff
   // when condition is met then $bool = true;
   // and double check
   if ($bool)
       break; //or header ('location'...);
}
// or here header location
```

If I understood correctly, this should help.

Comment: $_SESSION['CARRYTXNID'] = $txnidrow; 
    $_SESSION['txnId'] = true;
    if ($_SESSION['txnId']==true) {
 header('Location: ../confirmation');
 die();
    }

I tried this.. same thing, nothing happens

Comment: Dont add session, just add boolean variable. And var_dump that session everywhere to check its value and why it is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require '../config/connection.php';
session_name('ppRemember');
session_set_cookie_params(86400);
session_start();

$trans = $_SESSION['transaction_id'];
$clientId = $_SESSION['id'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['txnId'])){
    while ($_SESSION['txnId']!=true) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "#####", "#####", "######");
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `txn_id` FROM `trans` AS t, `order_table` AS ot, `customer_order_details` AS cod WHERE t.transaction_id=?
         && t.transaction_id = ot.transaction_id && ot.customer_order_details_id = cod.customer_order_details_id && cod.client_id=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ii',$trans,$clientId);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->store_result(); 
            $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
            if ($num_rows>=1) {
                $stmt->bind_result($txnidrow);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
                $_SESSION['CARRYTXNID'] = $txnidrow;    
                $_SESSION['txnId'] = true;

                header('Location: http://my-site.com/confirmation/');
                die();

            }
        }
    } 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What errors ( notices ) do you get? Does your script ever reach `$_SESSION['txnId'] = true;` condition line?

Comment: No errors or notices at all @Dainis Abols
Just does not redirect

Comment: It must do, as if I unset the variable, then run the script, then go directly to the confirmation page by typing in the url myself, it loads (the page only loads if the variable is set) @Dainis Abols

Comment: Debug it a bit. Do an `echo 'Test';` after every `if` and `while` condition and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the PHP, its the fact that your trying to issue a redirect header after outputing the page headers. Your while loop is after your entire page has been written. You can get around this by turning on output buffering in you php.ini OR simply by putting you while loop before any content.